# Python Django Regex: multiple optional arguments

Tags: python, django, regex

I use Django DRF @action decorator to create a search API view.

I would like to match all these url and capture parameters:

```py
# 'my_search' captured in search_terms var
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/medias/search/my_search/

# 'my_search' captured in search_terms var, and '1' captured in tags_id var
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/medias/search/my_search/tags/1/

# 'my_search' captured in search_terms var, and '1/2/' captured in tags_id var (or a list like [1,2])
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/medias/search/my_search/tags/1/2/
```

I actually have this code/regex, but that match only url with tags.

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path=r'search/(?P<search_terms>[^/]+)/tags/(?P<tags_id>[\d/]+)', url_name='search')
def search(self, request, search_terms, tags_id):
...
```

If someone have an idea it will be great.

Comment: Try it like this `search/(?P<search_terms>[^/]+)/(?:tags/(?P<tags_id>[\d/]+))?` https://regex101.com/r/8hY1qt/1

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's weird because it works perfectly on regex101.com, but django returns a 404 if there is no tags. 
NOT OK: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/medias/search/my_search/ 
OK: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/medias/search/my_search/tags/1/

Comment: I finally opted for 2 @action views: one with tags and the other without. Much better :)